# View source code enhanced by PostSharp 3.1

Tags: postsharp

I found this article http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Feature-Focus-View-source-code-enhanced-by-PostSharp and thats look awesome, but I can not found this option in my PostSharp 3.1 Ultimate. This feature was removed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this feature has been removed in PostSharp VS extension version 3.1.23.

The feature has been regularly broken by the decompiler vendors changing their command line APIs. Instead of having the feature that randomly breaks because of 3rd-party factors, we decided it's safer to deprecate this feature.

Comment: Sadly (( Is there a place where I could see how PostSharp enhance iterator method? Because I don't understand what will happen if my advices throw exception.

Comment: You can use one of the available IL disassembler tools (ildasm, Reflector, ILSpy, ...) to manually open the resulting assembly and find the method you're interested in. The only difference is that PostSharp no longer automates this process for you.